# How do I link my classes to the GUI class for interactive functionality in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

This is my server class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
public class Server {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public Server(ServerSocket serverSocket) {
        this.serverSocket = serverSocket;
    }

    public void startServer(){
        try{
            while(!serverSocket.isClosed()){
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("New client connected");
                ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(socket);
                Thread thread = new Thread(clientHandler);
                thread.start();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){

        }


    }
    public void closeServerSocket(){
        try{
            if(serverSocket!=null){
                serverSocket.close();
            }
       
 }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2000);
        Server server = new Server(serverSocket);
        server.startServer();
    }
}
```

This is my client class and theres also a clienthadler class which I wont show because it only describes the logic for multiple clients.

The client class...

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    private String username;

    public Client (Socket socket, String username){
        try{
            this.socket = socket;
            this.bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            this.bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            this.username = username;
        } catch(IOException e){
            closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter);
        }
    }
    public void sendMessage(){
        try{
            bufferedWriter.write(username);
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            bufferedWriter.flush();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
            while(socket.isConnected()){
                String messageToSend = scanner.nextLine();
                bufferedWriter.write(username + " " + messageToSend);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter);
        }
    }

    public void listenForMessage(){
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                String msgFromGroupChat;
                while(socket.isConnected()){
                    try{
                        msgFromGroupChat = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        System.out.println(msgFromGroupChat);

                    } catch (IOException e){
                        closeEverything(socket, bufferedReader, bufferedWriter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void closeEverything(Socket socket, BufferedReader bufferedReader, BufferedWriter bufferedWriter){
        try{
            if(bufferedReader!=null){
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            if(bufferedWriter!=null){
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
            if (socket!=null){
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your username for the group chat: ");
        String username = scanner.nextLine();
        Socket socket = new Socket ("localhost", 2000);
        Client client = new Client (socket, username);
        client.listenForMessage();
        client.sendMessage();
    }
}
```

**Now this is my SwingGUI class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GroupChatGUI extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JTextField txtName;
    private JButton btnClick;

    public GroupChatGUI() {
        btnClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnClick, txtName.getText()+" Hello " );
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GroupChatGUI gcg = new GroupChatGUI();
        gcg.setContentPane(gcg.mainPanel);
        gcg.setTitle(" Group chat");
        gcg.setSize(300, 400);
        gcg.setVisible(true);
        gcg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**The question is...**
How do I refer to the other classes from this class so that instead of outputting to the console, I can see the output in the GUI?
The application currently runs in the IDEA terminal. Its a group chat app where multiple users can connect to on client(my computer in this case and the start chatting)

Comment: Use an observer pattern, so when your Client class receives a message, it can notify interested parties. Just remember, Swing isn’t thread safe

Comment: i was thinking about nesting the classes and using interfaces